# JSF rendered is not working

Tags: java, ajax, jsf, jakarta-ee

I have something like this on my webpage, a select/drop down menu. This drop down menu should generate another drop down menu based on selected item. The way I am doing it, is by calling `<f:ajax event="change"..listener=..>`

But it is not happening as I expected. While selecting item in the dropdown menu trigger the listener in the ajax tag, the `rendered` property of the following drop down tables seems not affected by the changes. And the value for `rendered` changed successfully from false to true. Which..made me wonder what is wrong in my jsf page.

Here is the xhtml
'

```
                        <h:selectOneMenu value="#{teacher.viewCategory}">
                            <f:selectItem itemValue="0" itemLabel="Tahun" />
                            <f:selectItem itemValue="1" itemLabel="Mata Pelajaran" />
                            <f:ajax event="change" render="divYearSelection divCourseSelection"
                                    listener="#{teacher.enableViewCategory}"/>
                        </h:selectOneMenu>

                        <h:panelGroup id="divYearSelection" layout="block" rendered="#{teacher.showViewYearSelection}">
                            <h:outputText value="YEAR"/>
                        </h:panelGroup>

                        <h:panelGroup id="divCourseSelection" layout="block" rendered="#{teacher.showViewCourseSelection}">
                            <h:outputText value="COURSE"/>
                        </h:panelGroup>


                        <h:commandButton value="#{msg.tcr_form_submit_view}" action="#{teacher.viewTeacher}"/>
                    </h:panelGrid>
                </h:form>'
```

and this is the bean's function supporting the ajax

```
public void enableViewCategory(AjaxBehaviorEvent e) {       
        if (this.getViewCategory().equals("0")) {
            this.setShowViewYearSelection(true);
        } else {
            this.setShowViewCourseSelection(true);
        }
    }
```

When I debugged , the function works fine.

Comment: Does it work if you use `render="@form"` in your ajax command?

Comment: that does the trick! Would you mind explaining me more on ajax tag? Plus, do it so as an answer so that I could rate you. Thanks!

Comment: @Matt Could you please post this as answer so that I could rate it?

Comment: Just posted it! Good to hear that it works!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If partial rendering doesn't work a good starting point is to look into html source of your page as it is rendered in browser. Your `render="divYearSelection"` will only work if both (the ajax triggering component and the target component) have the same direct parent container.

Ids of rendered html components usually look like `id="formId:componentId:nestedComponentId1"` or `id="formId:componentId:nestedComponentId2"`

So a `render="nestedComponentId2"` called from component1 will only work if both ids have the same "trailer".

You could try to use the complete id as given in the example starting with the id of the form or alternatively (if the whole form is not too big) use `render="@form"` which updates the whole form.

Comment: I just had the same issue... `render="message"` nor `render=":message"` were working. I did `render="form:message"`, and it is working! Would you have the kindness to explain us why?