# JSF 2.0 - Ajax and Rendered Components

Tags: ajax, jakarta-ee, jsf-2

I'm experiencing some problems when using the "rendered" attribute with ajax behavior. I'll paste the code so I think it will be a lot more clear:

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{registrarVentaController.esCobroChequeString}">
  <f:selectItem itemLabel="Efectivo" itemValue="false"/>
  <f:selectItem itemLabel="Cheque" itemValue="true"/>
  <f:ajax  execute="@this" render="@form"/>
</h:selectOneMenu>

<h:panelGroup id="panelMonto">
    <span>Monto:</span>
    <h:inputText value="#{registrarVentaController.monto}" rendered="#{registrarVentaController.banCobroCheque}"/>
    <h:inputText value="#{registrarVentaController.monto}" rendered="#{not registrarVentaController.banCobroCheque}"/>    
</h:panelGroup>
```

My **"#{registrarVentaController}"** is just a View Scoped JSF Managed Bean with appropiate setters/getters.

This way it works, I mean, when user selects option "**Efectivo**", panelGroup "**panelMonto**" will get updated and we'll see the first inputText, and conversely when user selects option "**Cheque**" user will see the second inputText.

For this approach I used "**f:ajax**" component where I updated the whole **@form** to get this behavior work and I just want to update panelGroup "**panelMonto**" (using render="panelMonto" It doesn't work at all (I even try with full scope resolution **:formName:panelMonto** with no result).

I just want to have rendered work with ajax="idComponent" or similar behavior to show certain parts according what user have selected.

Best Regards!

**Note (One solution)**

> I managed to get a solution (taking as an input
>   [JSF rendered is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5906643/jsf-rendered-is-not-working)
>   and a bit of myself). I've just moved to a new form the part that I'm
>   interested in filtering according what user selected. This way I still
>   use @form ajax's render and it will just render this new form (not the
>   whole form as I was using!) Neverthless I'm still wondering if there
>   is a solution to not used @form and just the component/s ID.

Comment: In a nutshell, `render="@form"` works, but `render="panelMonto"` doesn't? Okay, is there more into the view? Isn't that `panelMonto` component actually inside another `UINamingContainer` component like `<ui:repeat>`, `<h:dataTable>`, `<f:subview>`, a composite component or something? What is its client ID in the generated HTML output (open page in browser, rightclick and *View Source* to find it)?

Comment: Thanks for remarking this aspects. The problem was around these things, I managed to solve it with a <h:panelGroup rendered="..."> ... </h:panelGroup> (The change I made is I placed rendered as an attribute for panelGroup component)

Answer (score 0):

what if you check with

```
render=":panelMonto"
```

not

```
render=":formName:panelMonto"
```

still not working?

this should work only with

```
render="panelMonto" //because is in the same form
```

Can you add more code?
Also can you check with your browser (in chrome: right click, inspect element, network) to see if there is any activity?? perhaps is rendering the same thing because of you...